# If file name contains specific text, display full name

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to have an application see if files contain a part of text. If it does contain it, I need to place it in a string (and/or display it).

So far, I have it working, as far as saying it is found or not, but I am unsure how to convert the results into a string.

```
 Dim dir As String = "C:\test\"
    Dim file As String()
    file = IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "1234" & "_*")
    If file.Length > 0 Then
        'Found
    Else
        'Not Found
    End If
```

When I try to add something like `Dim FileName as string = file` I get

> the value of type 1-dimensional array cannot be converted error

Or when I change `Dim file As String()` to `Dim file As String` I get the same error.

Comment: `GetFiles()` returns an array even if there is only one matching file;  you need to index `file` (as in `file(n)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`file` is *an array* of absolute paths to all found files. You have to iterate it using for example a [**`For Each` loop**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx).

For the sake of readability I suggest you rename it to `files`.

```
Dim files As String() = IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, "1234" & "_*")
For Each file As String In files
    Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(file)

    'Do your stuff here.

    'Logging each file (this is just an example).
    Console.WriteLine("File: " & file)
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " & fileName)
Next
```

The above will for example output:

```
File: C:\test\1234_a.txt
Name: 1234_a.txt
```

...into the console.

If you want to access only the first match you can do:

```
If files.Length > 0 Then
    Dim file As String = files(0) '0 is the first index, 1 is the second, and so on...
    Dim fileName As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(file)

    'Do your stuff here.
End If
```

Comment: You are a rockstar. Thanks so much!

Comment: @dwb : Not really, however I do play some piano ;) -- Glad I could help! Good luck!